# calculating Pi multithreading pthread

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, pi

I write the multithreaded program Pi calculating number. The number is considered until I won't send to process SIGINT signal then all flows stop and I receive the response. But unfortunately I can't understand a bug, then when I send a signal I sometimes I receive the wrong result - for example 4 or 3.17 is happens only when I send a signal if it is simple to come to the end by a certain number of iterations, everything is normal. Please help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>

union params {
    unsigned long long idx;
    double sum;
};

#define module (1299709L)
#define num_steps_per_check (1)

unsigned long long *CntIter = NULL;
int num_threads = 0;
int is_interrupted = 0;
pthread_rwlock_t rwlock = PTHREAD_RWLOCK_INITIALIZER;

void* partial_sum(void *ptr);

void handlesgint(int sig);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    double pi = 0;
    unsigned long long i;
    int opt;
    pthread_t* ids;
    union params* params;
    int ret_code = 0;

    // parse command line
    if (1 == argc) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s -n num_threads\n", argv[0]);
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "n:")) != -1)
    {
        switch (opt)
        {
            case 'n':
                num_threads = atoi(optarg);
                if (num_threads <= 0 /*|| num_threads >= _POSIX_THREAD_THREADS_MAX*/) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "quantity of threads invalid\n");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
                break;
            default:
                fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s -n num_threads\n", argv[0]);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    // setting handler
    if (SIG_ERR == signal(SIGINT, handlesgint)) {
        perror("fail signal");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // init memory
    params = (union params *)malloc(num_threads * sizeof(union params));
    CntIter = (unsigned long long *)calloc(num_threads, sizeof(long long));
    ids = (pthread_t *)malloc(num_threads * sizeof(pthread_t));

    // operation distribution
    for (i = 0; i < num_threads; ++i) {
        params[i].idx = i;
        ret_code = pthread_create(ids + i, NULL, partial_sum, (void*)(params + i));
        if (0 != ret_code) {
            perror("pthread create");
            exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    // joining
    for (i = 0; i < num_threads; ++i) {
        union params* res;
        ret_code = pthread_join(ids[i], (void **)&res);
        if (0 != ret_code) {
            perror("pthread join");
            exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        pi += res->sum;
    }

    pi *= 4.0;
    printf ("\npi = %.16f\n", pi);

    // free resources
    free(params);
    free(ids);
    free(CntIter);

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

void* partial_sum(void *ptr) {
    double sum = 0;
    int idx = ((union params *)ptr)->idx;
    unsigned long long i = 0;
    unsigned long long index = 0;
    int ret_code = 0;
    int terminating = 0;
    int sign = 0;
    sigset_t set;

    // Block SIGINT
    sigemptyset(&set);
    sigaddset(&set, SIGINT);
    ret_code = pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK, &set, NULL);
    if (0 != ret_code) {
        perror("fail sigmask");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    i = 0;
    while (0 == terminating) {
        index = num_threads * i + idx;
        sign = (0 == index % 2 ? 1 : -1);
        sum += sign * (1.0 / (2 * index + 1));

        CntIter[idx] = (CntIter[idx] + 1) % module;

        //if (i == 1000000L) { - !!!If to uncomment it and not to send a signal, result correct
        //  break;
        //}

        // check flag
        if (0 == (i % num_steps_per_check)) {
            pthread_rwlock_rdlock(&rwlock);
            if (1 == is_interrupted) {
                terminating = 1;
            }
            pthread_rwlock_unlock(&rwlock);
        }
        ++i;
    }

    ((union params *)ptr)->sum = sum;
    return ptr;
}

void handlesgint(int sig) {
    pthread_rwlock_wrlock(&rwlock);
    is_interrupted = 1;
    pthread_rwlock_unlock(&rwlock);
}
```

Comment: You're saying that if the calculation stops early, you don't get an accurate result. Isn't it expected? E.g. if you have only one thread, that stopped after one iteration, you'll get 4.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Corrected code I spread the following post. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>

union params {
    unsigned long long idx;
    double sum;
};

#define module (1299709L)
#define num_steps_per_check (10)

unsigned long long *CntIter = NULL;
unsigned long long max_iter = 0;
int num_threads = 0;
int is_interrupted = 0;
pthread_rwlock_t rwlock = PTHREAD_RWLOCK_INITIALIZER;

void* partial_sum(void *ptr);

void handlesgint(int sig);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    double pi = 0;
    unsigned long long i;
    int opt;
    pthread_t* ids;
    union params* params;
    int ret_code = 0;

    // parse command line
    if (1 == argc) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s -n num_threads\n", argv[0]);
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "n:")) != -1)
    {
        switch (opt)
        {
            case 'n':
                num_threads = atoi(optarg);
                if (num_threads <= 0 /*|| num_threads >= _POSIX_THREAD_THREADS_MAX*/) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "quantity of threads invalid\n");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
                break;
            default:
                fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s -n num_threads\n", argv[0]);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    // setting handler
    if (SIG_ERR == signal(SIGINT, handlesgint)) {
        perror("fail signal");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // init memory
    params = (union params *)malloc(num_threads * sizeof(union params));
    CntIter = (unsigned long long *)calloc(num_threads, sizeof(long long));
    ids = (pthread_t *)malloc(num_threads * sizeof(pthread_t));

    // operation distribution
    for (i = 0; i < num_threads; ++i) {
        params[i].idx = i;
        ret_code = pthread_create(ids + i, NULL, partial_sum, (void*)(params + i));
        if (0 != ret_code) {
            perror("pthread create");
            exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    // joining
    for (i = 0; i < num_threads; ++i) {
        union params* res;
        ret_code = pthread_join(ids[i], (void **)&res);
        if (0 != ret_code) {
            perror("pthread join");
            exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        pi += res->sum;
    }

    pi *= 4.0;
    printf ("\npi = %.16f\n", pi);

    // free resources
    free(params);
    free(ids);
    free(CntIter);

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

void* partial_sum(void *ptr) {
    double sum = 0;
    int idx = ((union params *)ptr)->idx;
    unsigned long long i = 0;
    unsigned long long index = 0;
    int ret_code = 0;
    int terminating = 0;
    int sign = 0;
    sigset_t set;

    // Block SIGINT
    sigemptyset(&set);
    sigaddset(&set, SIGINT);
    ret_code = pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK, &set, NULL);
    if (0 != ret_code) {
        perror("fail sigmask");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    i = 0;
    while (0 == terminating) {
        index = num_threads * i + idx;
        sign = (0 == index % 2 ? 1 : -1);
        sum += sign * (1.0 / (2 * index + 1));


        //fprintf(stderr, "thread : %d iterate - %lld index : %lld\n", idx, i, index);

        CntIter[idx] = (CntIter[idx] + 1) % module;

        // if (i == 1000000L) {
        //  break;
        // }

        // check flag
        if (0 == (i % num_steps_per_check)) {
            pthread_rwlock_rdlock(&rwlock);
            if (1 == is_interrupted) {
                terminating = 1;
            }
            pthread_rwlock_unlock(&rwlock);
        }
        ++i;
    }

    // complete iterations
    for (; i < max_iter; ++i) {
        index = num_threads * i + idx;
        sign = (0 == index % 2 ? 1 : -1);
        sum += sign * (1.0 / (2 * index + 1));
    }

    //fprintf(stderr, "FINISH : thread : %d iterate - %lld\n", idx, i);

    ((union params *)ptr)->sum = sum;
    return ptr;
}

void handlesgint(int sig) {
    unsigned long long i;

    max_iter = 0;
    pthread_rwlock_wrlock(&rwlock);

    // find max iterations
    for (i = 0; i < num_threads; ++i) {
        if (CntIter[i] > max_iter) {
            max_iter = CntIter[i];
        }
    }

    is_interrupted = 1;
    pthread_rwlock_unlock(&rwlock);
}
```